# Did "drink to someone" imply the same thing back then?

Tags: meaning, poetry, ben-jonson

In a popular song [Drink To Me Only with Thine Eyes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drink_to_Me_Only_with_Thine_Eyes), first published in 1616 as [To Celia](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Oxford_Book_of_English_Verse_1250-1900/To_Celia) by Ben Jonson, did the phrase **drink to someone** mean the same thing as nowadays, i.e. **to say cheers for someone?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So far, the earliest citation of that "drink to someone" phrase is from 1700, albeit in a context where they explain "toast" as being equivalent to "to drink to his health", which suggests it was a known phrase.

Comment: @Sean Duggan: It was used in Shakespeare: "I drink to the general joy o' the whole table" (*Macbeth*) "With drinking healths to my niece: I'll drink to
 her as long as there is a passage in my throat and
 drink in Illyria: he's a coward and a coystrill
 that will not drink to my niece till his brains turn
 o' the toe like a parish-top" (*Twelfth Night*)

Comment: @PeterShor: *facepalm* As an actor, I should have thought of that. Well spotted!

Answer (score 3):

Shakespeare's plays preceded Ben Jonson's song. And Shakespeare uses *drink to* with this meaning:

> I drink to the general joy o' the whole table. (*Macbeth*)

> With drinking healths to my niece: I'll drink to her as long as there is a passage in my throat and drink in Illyria: he's a coward and a coystrill that will not drink to my niece till his brains turn o' the toe like a parish-top. (*Twelfth Night*)

There is another definition listed in the OED that was current then,

> To hand or present beverage for his use; to give drink to. *Obsolete*.
> 1470–1485, T. Malory, *Morte d'Arthur*: Thenne they lough and made good chere and eyther dranke to other frely.

However, this earlier meaning doesn't seem possible in Ben Jonson's song.